# error LNK2019 :unresolved external symbol_main referenced in function tmainCRTsetup

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I'm new to Visual Studio using it first time for my project to create a gui for serial port communication.I'm using version 2013.I created CLR emty project and then added windows form app in source file and then serial port and combobox from tool box then build it and got this error. I've tried all settings changed system to subsystem windows and entry point to main then again to wWinMainCRTStartup but it's still there.Kindly help :(

Comment: Did you actually write any code?

Comment: Well that seems to be the problem, the error is saying that you should write a function called `main`.

Comment: @john Thanks! I deleted previous project and started again after adding code to display the form it worked .